# Make link from Backstretch image?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm using [Backstretch](https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch) as a way to get a nice consistent user-experience cross-browser, inside a Ruby on Rails project. The images are actually instances of the `SalesPage` model, and have, next to the image url, a title and an url attached to them.

I load the images as follows:

```
- images = []
- sales_pages_images = []
- @sales_pages.each do |page|
- images << "'#{page.images.first.image.url}'"

#backgroundImageSlider
  :javascript
  var images = [#{images.join(",")}];
  $(images).each(function(){ $("<img/>")[0].src = this; });
  var index = 0;
  setInterval(function() { index = (index >= images.length - 1) ? 0 : index + 1;       $.backstretch(images[index]);}, 5000);
$.backstretch(images[index], {speed: 500});
```

This works fine. except for the fact that I want to make the images into a link. I want the background images clickable, and link them to an url from the database. I'm no javascript hero, so I can't get it to work :(

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Try this! :)

assuming in your markup you have a `<a>` tag immediately surrounding your `<img/>` tag then in your view ...

```
- images = @sales_pages.inject([]) do |images, sales_page|
    - images << "sales_page.images.first.image.url"

  :javascript
    $imageTag = $("img");
    $imageLink = $imageTag.parent()
    $imageTag.backstretch(#{images}, { duration: 5000, fade: 500, });
    $(window).on("backstretch.after", function (e, instance, index) {
      $imageLink.attr('href') = #{@sales_pages[index].link};
    });
```